# Correct terminology about "probability measures" and "probability distributions"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, borel-measures

**INTRODUCTION.** Let's consider some previous answers (from previous questions) about "probability measure" and "probablity distributions":

**(Previous question 1)** [Distinguishing probability measure, function and distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073744/distinguishing-probability-measure-function-and-distribution#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20between%20the%20terms,way%20the%20terms%20are%20used.),

**(Previous answer 1.1)** [Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy) wrote:

> The difference between the terms "probability measure" and "probability distribution" is in some ways more of a difference in connotation of the terms rather than a difference between the things that the terms refer to. It's more about the way the terms are used.
> A probability distribution or a probability measure is a function assigning probabilities to measurable subsets of some set.

**(Previous answer 1.2)** While [Maverick Meerkat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/342736/maverick-meerkat) wrote:

> I think "Probability Distribution" might mean either of these things, but I think most often it will be used in less mathematically precise as it's sort of an umbrella term - it can refer to the distribution of measure on the original space, or the distribution of measure on the real line, characterized by the CDF or PDF/PMF.
>
> Usually, if there's no need to go deep into the math, people will stay on the level of "probability function" or "probability distribution". Though some will venture to the realms of "probability measure" without real justification except the need to be absolutely mathematically precise.

**(Previous question 2)** [Probability measure and distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268066/probability-measure-and-distribution)

**(Previous answer 2.1)** [ncmathsadist](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4154/ncmathsadist) wrote:

> Every right continuous nondecreasing function $:ℝ→[0,1]$ with $(∞)=1$ and $(−∞)=0$ is a probability distribution, where $_()=_((−∞,]),∈ℝ$ and $_$ is a Borel measure on $ℝ$.

**SUMMARY OF THE INTRODUCTION.** To my understanding, it looks like tha we can call "probability measures" as "probability distributions", and viceversa. It looks like that "probability distributions" is a shallow term, while "probability measures" is a deeper term, used in probability theory. Right or wrong?

**MY QUESTION**

I am currently using a number of measures of distances/divergences among pairs of "probability distributions" $P$ and $Q$, and I would like to use also the [Wasserstein distance $W_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric). However, $W_1$ is defined for "probability measures", $\mu$ and $\nu$, i.e. $W_1(\mu,\nu)$. **Therefore, can I still call the two "probability measures", $\mu$ and $\nu$, as "probability distributions", like $P$ and $Q$?**

Comment: "Distribution" is not particularly well defined, though it is widely understood in various forms. The measure-theoretic approach and language is designed to generalise statements so you do not not need to deal with different cases separately: for example you can have a probability mass function or a density or [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution) or a mixture of these, and you do not want to cover all the cases individually; similarly a cumulative distribution function only really works with $\mathbb R$ and its subsets or at a stretch $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: They are the same thing, synonyms. No difference.

Comment: Great answers from all of you !! Many many thanks !! Btw, if any of you feels to write the answer in the section "Answer Your Question", I would be happy to accept and upvoting